# Why the coco-annotator I installed doesn't have delete option?

Tags: python-3.x, docker, docker-compose, keypoint

I installed manually the coco-annotator in the Ubuntu server of my company. Because it can't connect to external network(including docker website), so I need to install docker(v20.10.7), docker compose(v2.22.0), and the images(required in docker-compose.yml) manually. But when I type docker-compose up, the website has some error. I can't delete the dataset or the categories I created. And I can't set the key point class when I tried to create a pose category. How can I fix it?

1.when I was creating pose category, it showed like this:

[image]

But the expected result should be  like this:

[image]

That is to say, there is no "+" button at the right corner of the 'keypoint' label.

2. when I want to delete categories or datasets,it showed like this:
   [image]

But the expected result should be  like this:

[image]

That is to say, there is no "..." button at the right corner of every categories label, which has the delete option in it.

Comment: `the website has some error` -- have you checked the logs? This doesn't look like it's docker related at all, more like a general software question.